# how to pass a parameter to a function if the event is also required as a param?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 functions `addData()` and `diplayInfoBox(e)`, inside addData I have a click handler, I need to get some event details when clicked so the event is required as a parameter of `displayInfoBox`, I also need to pass another piece of information into `displayInfoBox` but I'm unsure how to do this with the event being there. If I do `displayInfoBox(e, pin)` this doesn't work. Can anyone suggest what I need to do to resolve this?

**JSFiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/kyllle/upej8/7/

**JS**

```
addData: function() {
  //code

  //click handler
  Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(pin, 'click', instance.displayInfoBox); //need to be able to pass variable pin to displayInfoBox
},

displayInfoBox: function(e) { //need to accept additional param for pin

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
  Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(pin, 'click', function(e){instance.displayInfoBox(e, pin);});
```

So you basically call an anonymous function onclick which in turn calls your function passing in any parameters you want -remember to include the event ('e' in this case) as well

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(pin, 'click', function (event) {
    instance.displayInfoBox(event, pin);
});
```